# Failed to load Payment Method in System->Configuration in Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, payment-methods, magento-community, ce-1.8.1.0

I am using **Magento CE 1.8.1** and when I go to **System->Configuration** and click on "**payment methods**", It doesn't go anywhere. It tries loading and fails without any error at :

http://www.yantrascollection.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/payment/key/e231c4cfbded937e9ac9070c38fed05e/

It is a **clean install** from the new download of their website, and I don't know what is wrong.

This is my first try with Magento so I may not have done something right.

Please, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you provide the actual error message? Or maybe a screen capture of what you see?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using PHP 5.4?  If so, you will run into an error on that page involving one of the models for Sales/Order.  Downgrade to PHP 5.3.24 or there is a patch available for 5.4 from Magento

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductTierPrice/catalogProductTierPrice.html